# calling a function inside class model.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have 2 functions inside model.js,  findUser(id) and findById(userId). they are both inside class. Inside findById(userId), I want to call findUser(id). how can I do that?

```
findUser(id) {
                let foundUsers = users.filter(function(user) {
                    if(user.id === id) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
    
                if(foundUsers.length > 0) {
                    return foundUsers[0];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    
    
    
         findById(userId) {
            // Find user by Id
            // Returns user, or null if not present
    }
```

Comment: Since they are inside a class, 1. they are referred to as methods (as I understand it), and 2. it should be as easy as `classname.myfunction();` or `classname.mymethod();`.

Comment: should it be classname.myfunction(); or classname.myfunction(userId); ? I am a  beginner so I feel lost.

Comment: The latter `classname.myfunction(userId)`, since it has a "parameter". I am kind of trash at OOP, and not entirely sure how well this is going to work out. So usually when you want to call a method, the object has already been created (commonly known as instantiation). You know you have created a new object (as a programmer) when you have used the keyword `new` before the class object... so in JS, `myCar = new Car(...);`. `myCar` as it was called holds a reference to that object in memory, and stores all the potential methods to be called in shape, form, or fashion.

Comment: What I am unsure about (because I haven't tried it), is if one can simply call a method from an objects class without it being defined. So something like `myCar_anotherVariable = Car().myMethod();` shouldn't work, unless you have - for a lack of better words - like a null constructor... as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use "this".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not a good practice to call a method inside a model class.
So better create a model object out side and call each functions accordingly.

Create a new object of that class

```
let model1 = new Model();
```

Call that function using dot operator.

```
model1.findUser(id);
model1.findById(userId);
```